# How to get multiple values within an li

Tags: javascript, node.js, webautomation, playwright

I'm working with Playwright to scrape a directory. I'm able to get each "block" of content like this:

```
let nestedElementsToCapture = ['.title', '.subhead', '#url']
    this.page.$$eval('li', (spans) =>
        spans.map((span) => span.innerText)
    );
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the defined nested elements within each "block".

For instance:
`li > .title`, `li > .subhead`, `li > #url`

How would I go about capturing those elements for each block?  Right now all I get is one big string of text that contains all the text within each `li`

Answer (score -1):

I would pass that array to the `$$eval` function, solve everything inside that function and then return some kind of object.
I set the argument name as `childSelectors`, so it's clear that you can't access to the `nestedElementsToCapture` variable inside the function.

```js
let nestedElementsToCapture = ['.title', '.subhead', '#url']
this.page.$$eval(
   'li', 
    (spans, childSelectors) => {
        return spans.map((span) => {
            let result = { 
                title = span.querySelector(childSelectors[0]).innerText,
                subHead = span.querySelector(childSelectors[1]).innerText,
                url = span.querySelector(childSelectors[2]).innerText,
            };
      
            return result;
        });
    },
    nestedElementsToCapture);
```